# Click on Spin in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

```
<hs-details-item ng-repeat="item in amenities" style="overflow:hidden" class="ng-scope">
            <hs-label class="ng-binding">Coca-Cola</hs-label>
            <hs-value-block>
                <hs>
                    <hs-spin ng-class="{'disabled': isAmenityPosting}" spin- ontrol="{changeCallback:setQuantity, value: item.quantity, min:0, params: item.amenity_id, title:'Quantity'}"><span class="disabled">-</span><span>+</span>
                        <!--<span hs-placeholder="0" localize="{data: item.quantity > 0 ? item.quantity:null, format: 'int', operation:'text'}"></span>-->
                        <span localize="{data: item.quantity, format: 'int', operation:'text'}">0</span>
                    </hs-spin>
                </hs>
            </hs-value-block>
        </hs-details-item>
```

Scenario: I need to click on a spin which is a “+” button which in turns increment numbers every time is clicked.
Challenge: I have 10 spins for different items. How can I make my code unique so it would click on the right spin? I can see the names of the items are unique (water, Coca Cola,….) but those are not the one being clicked. Any idea how I can do this in Protractor? The following Snippet code is one example which is used to increment the number of Coca Cola once the spin is clicked. When I select my element which is a “+” button it would refer to the following coed which has notting unique about it:

```
<hs-spin ng-class="{'disabled': isAmenityPosting}" spin- ontrol="{changeCallback:setQuantity, value: item.quantity, min:0, params: item.amenity_id, title:'Quantity'}"><
```

Comment: Tried following but got an error: No element found using locator: by binding("Coca cola")                                                                                                 element(by.binding('Coca-Cola')).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minor change to alecxe's suggestion I made this to work and was able to click "+" button:

```
element(by.xpath("//hs-details-item[hs-label='Coca-Cola']//hs-spin/span[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) out the desired spin element based on the label:

```
var desiredLabel = "Coca-Cola";
var desiredSpin = element.all(by.repeater("item in amenities")).filter(function (spin) {
    return spin.element(by.tagName("hs-label")).getText().then(function (label) {
        return label === desiredLabel;
    });
}).first();

desiredSpin.element(by.tagName("hs-spin")).click();
```

Or, sort of a [non-welcomed](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/style-guide#locator-strategies) way in Protractor - use an XPath expression and get to it in one go:

```
var desiredSpin = element(by.xpath("//hs-details-item[hs-label = 'Coca-Cola']//hs-spin"));
desiredSpin.click();
```

Comment: @ alecxe : I tried both of your suggestions but they did not click on the spin. I did not get any errors

Comment: @ alecxe : I think we are getting closer. After your update, I run it and this time the click was in a section that was not intended. So to be clear, the target is a rectangle that is divided in 3 sections. Left side is a “-“ button which decrement the number, right side is a “+” button which increment the number, the middle section is a field which if it is clicked it will pop-up a window so the user can put a number manually.

Comment: @ alecxe    Cont… Your updated command click on the middle part which requires another action. The user seldom use that field. What the user does is to click on the “+” or “-“ buttons. For my test, I like to click on the “+” button.
 If you look at the snippet code there is a line which start with “span localize” and there is a value of “0”.
Each time I click on the “+” button that number increases.  
Your XPATH command does the same.

Comment: @Kevin okay, thanks, what if you would use `element(by.xpath("//hs-details-item[hs-label = 'Coca-Cola']//hs-spin/span[. = '+']"));`?

Comment: @ alecxe, Thanks for the update. I tried your latest update but there was no click on "+" button... There was no error either